# Want to change RDP Port (Remote Desktop Connection) without losing remote access

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, windows-server-2008

I want to change the default Port of 3389 used for RDP to my Server (Windows Web Server 2008 R2) to another Port.

I have Kaspersky anti-virus (no firewall) and Windows Firewall with Advanced Security running.

The trick - or the main thrust of my question - is I simply **cannot** lose the access to this Server.  (ie *I cannot make a mistake*, as I do not have physical access to the machine to be able to fix any errors I make.  Remote access only.  If I break this - it could cost hundreds of $$ for someone else to physically revert the changes for me - on the other side of the world.)

Is there a way I can test my changes - while remotely accessing the machine - before 'switching' over to the new Port number?

I understand I need to change the Port number in:

- Windows Firewall
- Registry for RDP

I also understand I can use

> netstat -a

to see which Ports are being listened to.

So I guess I am after a *contingency plan* plus the correct order of execution of certain steps to reduce my chance of making a mistake.

Comment: I would install vnc with a really strong password as a backup, make sure I can access and then make the changes.

Comment: Thanks, thats a super idea - as a backup method :)  Does that need a specific Port too?  Or does it use 80?  (Not that it matters, its still a super idea, I will investigate)

Comment: I think that the default port is 9100